# Get email body from outlook with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, outlook

I'm writing a program that pulls in email, parses it and then stores the entries in a database. So far I can get the subject of the email but when I try to pull in the body I get a COMException ("Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"). I tried pulling it as the HTMLBody instead but neither is working. I'm using VS2008 and Outlook 2003. Help? If more information is needed let me know....

Updated to add: I have seriously googled my brains out on this error. I have no idea what is causing it, I have NO IDEA why it's throwing this, I can't find a way to map it to a better error so I know what's going on and it's driving me crazy.

So. To recap: Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to access Outlook 2007. Cannot pull the body of an email using ((Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[1]).Body.ToString(). However, can pull the Subject, ReceivedTime and various other things. Also can't save an email to a different location because I get the same com error. No one else has ever had this error in the history of google? Help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8717441/1128539
... for answer to similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following article very helpful in understanding Outlook messages.

[Reading an Outlook MSG File in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/reading_an_outlook_msg.aspx)

Comment: That's a cool article! I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook stuff though. The subject and date received are coming through fine, I just can't get the body of the message.